# How can i get only 1 value from table for each client and get all values from the same but with different value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need query to build where,if client has statuses '5' then i get all rows, if client has only '6' statuses then i get only one from it and latest

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
ClientID INT NULL,
StatusID INT NULL,
Date DATE null

)
INSERT INTO #test
(
    ClientID,
    StatusID,
    Date
)
SELECT 1001,5,'20190909'
UNION all
SELECT 1001,5,'20190908'
UNION  all
SELECT 1002,5,'20190909'
UNION  all
SELECT 1002,6,'20190910'
UNION  all
SELECT 1003,6,'20190909'
UNION all
SELECT 1003,6,'20190910'
```

Comment: Can you please provide input and expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question states if a client has any rows with `StatusID = 5` then you want all rows for that client. If a client only has `StatusID = 6` rows you just want the latest row.

The below SQL does this

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                HasStatus5 = SIGN(SUM(IIF(StatusID = 5, 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID)),
                LatestDate = MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID)
         FROM   #test
         WHERE  StatusID IN ( 5, 6 ))
SELECT ClientID,
       StatusID,
       Date
FROM   T
WHERE  HasStatus5 = 1
        OR Date = LatestDate
```

Comment: Hello, it will show 2 rows for client with ClientID = 1002, how can i modify script to show only 5, that was my struggle

Answer (score 0):

If **latest** mean max(date) then :

```
select top 1  *
from
 test
 where StatusID=6
union  all(

select * from 
test
 where StatusID=5)
order by Date desc
```

check this [sqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/367e0/33)